# populating listview with the result of another Activity

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

i want to implement following things in my project.
from activity A i want to start activity B for result.
activity A has a listview(say mylistview) and an adapter set for it. (say myadapter).
and the corresponding arraylist myarraylist.

with the result string from activity B i want to add that string to the existing listview of activity A.

i have done following things:

in activity A:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.r.layout.simple_list_item_1,myarraylist);
mylistview.setListAdapter(myadapter);

Intent i = new Intent(this, activityB.class);
startAcivityForResult(i,1);
```

now in my onActivityResult method :

```
String new_str = data.getStringExtra();
myarraylist.add(new_str);
myadapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

and in Activity B:

```
Intent i =new Intent();
i.putExtra("card_name", Card_name);
setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
```

my program does not show any errors and works fine .
but still my listview is not getting updated properly.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by not getting updated properly? You mean sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: no sorry , i framed it wrong, it never gets updated.....

Comment: please see my edited question..... i have added what i have done in Activity B

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to debug what's wrong. Either the String is not properly read or the string never reaches the listview.

If the String is not read, try sending it in the intent instead. And if it's added to the array, but not to the listview, i would try to update the adapter so that it read directly from the array.

Like so:

```
    public class CustomStringAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CustomStringAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myarraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myarraylist.get(position);
    }

}
```

And then set that as an adapter instead:

```
CustomStringAdapter myadapter = new CustomStringAdapter(this,android.r.layout.simple_list_item_1,myarraylist);
mylistview.setListAdapter(myadapter);
```

This might not be the answer, but it's worth to test.